# How would you bind a dynamic value to a dynamic component in Handlebars/EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm creating a dynamic table component (one row per model), that will include components dynamically (one column for each object in config, each object relates to a key in a model).

I'm trying to bind the model key to the dynamic model.

Any ideas on how to do that given the following?

**Config object:**

deployment.js (controller)

```
EDConfig: {
    controller: this, 
    modelType: 'EscalationDetailModelGroup',
    table: {
        cols: [{
            header: 'Escalation Time',
            cname: 'form-input-text',
            content: {
               value: model.escalationTime //obviously this wont work
            }
        },{
            header: 'Most Complex Alarm Level',
            field: 'mostComplexAlarmLevelDispatched',
            cname: 'form-input-text',
            content: {
               value: model.escalationTime //obviously this wont work
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

**Router Model:**

deployment.js (router)

```
modelRange: [{
    id: 1,
    escalationTime: '3 hours',
    mostComplexAlarmLevelDispatched: 'N/A'
}, {
    id: 2,
    escalationTime: '45 minutes',
    mostComplexAlarmLevelDispatched: 'Level 3'
}]
```

**Templates:**

deployment.hbs

```
<h2>Deployments</h2>
        {{table-list
            config=EDConfig
            data=model.escalationDetailModelGroups
        }}
```

table-list.hbs

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each col in config.table.cols}}
                <th>{{col.header}}</th>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each record in modelRange}}
        <tr>
            {{#each col in config.table.cols}}
            <td>
                {{component col.cname content=col.content}}
            </td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What you want is to have the value of `record` (from the each loop) in each of the `cols.content.value`? Where is this config object coming from? I think its time for http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Added a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how are you trying to merge/link the data, but I doesn't seem to be really important.

I don't think its necessary to pass two data sources to your `table-list`, the relationships between config and model are not something that you should be doing in the templates. Its more of a data-decoration process and that type of thing should be done at the controller level.

How about something like:

```
// controller
tableRows: function() {
  var config = this.get('config');
  var model = this.get('model');
  config.forEach(function(col) {
    // give each col a model reference
  });
  return config;
}.property('config', 'model')

// template
{{table-list data=tableRows}}
```

I just typed that off the top of my head, tweaks would be needed most likely, but the idea should be clear.

Comment: Each table row represents a model inside the `modelRange` array, each column in that row is an attribute of that model. The config specifies which attributes to display and which component to use to display them with. The example you provided doesn't really help me resolve my issue. I'm not sure if you are misunderstanding the question or if I just need more information to understand your answer.

Comment: a jsbin would make a big difference, instead of pseudocode, I don't have time to set it up

Comment: I've found a different approach if you would be interested in taking a look at me new question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851163/accessing-the-current-model-within-a-yield